# Sent leftjoin querybuilder rsult to twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex, query-builder

i have a leftjoin with doctrine querybuilder

```
$registros = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$registros->select('u,v')
->from('Entity\RegistroCam', 'u')
->leftjoin('Entity\CmMunicipios','v','WITH','u.camMunicipio = v.idMunicipio')
->orderBy('u.camPaterno', 'DESC');

$query = $registros->getQuery();

// Execute Query
$result = $query->getResult();
```

My problem is when I send the result to twig , it throws the following error

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: Method "idRegistro" for object "Entity\CmMunicipios" does not exist in "adminPanel.twig.html" at line 87
```

if i write

```
$registros->select('u')
```

works perfectly

Comment: syntax is like this: `select(array('u', 'v', 'x', 'y'))`

Comment: DQL is not SQL, try: ->leftjoin('u.camMunicipio','v') though I suspect that based on your usage of idMunicipio, you probably don't have your object relations setup correctly.  Think objects, not id's.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments, I found the solution after several hours of searching, I just had to do in twig {{ registro.idMunicipio.getMunCompuesto }} @Cerad